# redirect stderr stdout both on console and log file

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr

I am using a C API in order to manage my bluetooth thru bluetoothctl. It works by using command like :

```
./BT_API connect $2 | bluetoothctl > /tmp/BT_TMP
```

All is stored within /tmp/BT_TMP but noting on screen. I tried by using the following command

```
./BT_API connect $2 | bluetoothctl 2>&1 /tmp/BT_TMP
```

But now all is displayed on screen but file /tmp/BT_TMP is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `tee`, which will redirect the stdin to both a file and stdout:

```
./BT_API connect $2 | bluetoothctl 2>&1 | tee /tmp/BT_TMP
```